# External Direct Product

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, direct-product, quotient-group

Let $S_n$ denote the symmetric group on $n$ symbols. The group $S_3\oplus(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)$ is isomorphic to which of the following groups?

1.$\Bbb Z/12\Bbb Z$

2.$\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$

3.$ A_4$, the alternating group of order $12$

4.$ D_6$ the dihedral group of order $12$.

I can easily discard option 1st and 2nd. Since $S_3$ is non abelian implies $S_3\oplus(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)$ s non abelian. But I have problem to deal with other options. Will be pleased if you share your valuable knowledge.

Comment: Your group will have an element of order six.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

Since $((123), [1]_2)$ has order six and $A_4$ has no element of order six, the answer must be 4., the dihedral group $D_6$.